# How to design mongoose schema design for nested data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, database-design

I am building a MERN stack app where I want to have nested data. I am unable to figure out the mongoose schema design. There should be details like `name`, `age`, `photo` nested under `year`. Below is a rough idea of what it should look idea. The year shouldn't be hard coded in the schema.

```
        2017 :{
            name: "Tony",
            age: 21,
            photo: "some url here"
          },
          {
            name: "Steve",
            age: 21,
            photo: "some url here"
          }
        2018 :{
            name: "Stark",
            age: 19,
            photo: "some url here"
          },
          {
            name: "Rogers",
            age: 21,
            photo: "some url here"
          }
```

Comment: It's a very rough idea since it's not even a valid object structure. Lists of things belong in arrays and named kjeys don't have lists without that. In all honesty *"nested"* is actually the worst possible thing you could do. Great for quick lookups in client code, but horrible and un-workable for a database. Just do `{ year: 2018, name: "Stark", age: 19, photo: "some url here" }` as the *"nesting"* actually does more harm than the good you are presuming it does.

Answer (score 0):

you could break it into two schemas. PhotoAlbums that contain an array of photo object references. Each document in albums schema could be a year or generic album name grouping similar photos together. Photos schema would store the actual photo document with filename and URI.

```
PhotoAlbumSchema:
{
   name: String,
   year: Number,
   photos: [{ type: Schema.types.ObjectId, ref: "Photo"}] // array of photo objects
}
```

and

```
PhotoSchema
{
    filename: String,
    uri: String,
    description: String,
}
```

each document you insert into the albums schema can link an array of photo object references (ObjectIds). even better each album can contain shared sets of photos across multiple albums. you populate the data by doing a Albums.find({}).populate('Photo')